# Arrow Key implementation javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-physics

ive been trying to flip the arrows when the cars are in different side of the road. The image shows two multi-lane roads where forward on the left side goes up and i want forward on the right to go down, and the same for right and left. ive tried my method but it doesnt seem to work so i think im doing something stupid. please hep with a method that can work, heres the code

```
class Controls 
{
    constructor(type,laneIndex)
    {
        this.laneIndex = laneIndex;
        this.forward =false;
        this.left = false ;
        this.foward = false ;
        this.reverse =false;
        switch (type)
        {
            case "KEYS":
               this.#addKeyboardListeners();
               break;
            case "DUMMY":
                this.forward =true;
                break;
        }
       
    }

    
    #addKeyboardListeners()
    {  
        if (this.laneIndex <= 3)
            {
                document.onkeydown=(event)=>
                {
                    switch(event.key)
                    {
                        case "ArrowLeft":
                            this.left =true;
                            break;
        
                        case "ArrowRight":
                            this.right =true;
                            break;
        
                        case "ArrowUp":
                            this.forward =true;
                            break;
                                               
                        case "ArrowDown":
                            this.reverse =true;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                document.onkeyup=(event)=>
                {
                    switch(event.key)
                    {
                        case "ArrowLeft":
                            this.left = false;
                            break;
        
                        case "ArrowRight":
                            this.right = false;
                            break;
        
                        case "ArrowUp":
                            this.forward = false;
                            break;
                                               
                        case "ArrowDown":
                            this.reverse =false;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (this.laneIndex >= 4)
            {
                document.onkeydown=(event)=>
                {
                    switch(event.key)
                    {
                        case "ArrowLeft":
                            this.right =true;
                            break;
        
                        case "ArrowRight":
                            this.left =true;
                            break;
        
                        case "ArrowUp":
                            this.reverse =true;
                            break;
                                               
                        case "ArrowDown":
                            this.forward =true;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                document.onkeyup=(event)=>
                {
                    switch(event.key)
                    {
                        case "ArrowLeft":
                            this.right =false;
                            break;
        
                        case "ArrowRight":
                            this.left =false;
                            break;
        
                        case "ArrowUp":
                            this.reverse =false;
                            break;
                                               
                        case "ArrowDown":
                            this.forward =false;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

[image: two one way multi-lane roads]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Basic keyboard input

This answer shows a method for monitoring the ongoing keyboard state.

Keys of interest are flagged as true when down and false when up.

There is a demo (bottom) to show how this method can be used in an animated app interface.

### Some pointers

- Keep IO (mouse, keyboards, touch, joysticks etc..) and game logic separate as this help keeps the code simple.
- Don't add events via the named event property. Eg `document.onkeydown = function`. As it can easily be overwritten by you or 3rd party code.

  Use `addEventListener` to ensure the event will stay in place

### Example of keyboard input

The example creates an object `keys` that has a property for each of the keys you want to keep track of. The keyboard event listener will set the state to true when a key is down and false if not.

You can add other keys by adding the [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) name to keys object. Example I have added `Space` to listen for the space key (I will use it to switch tracks in next example.

```
const keys = (() => {
    const keys = { // only names of keys you are interested in
        ArrowUp: false,
        ArrowRight: false,
        ArrowDown: false,
        ArrowLeft: false,
        Space: false,
    };
    function listener(e) {
        keys[e.code] !== undefined && (keys[e.code] = e.type === "keydown");
    }
    addEventListener("keyup", listener);
    addEventListener("keydown", listener);
    return keys;
})();
```

### Using the input

Once you have the controlling input setup, your app logic need only monitor the state of the input and react as needed.

The example below uses the `keys` object to move the active car. `W` moves the car forward, and `D` moves it in reverse. The function that moves cars is `Car.update`

To switch cars press the space key. Switching cars can be found in `renderLoop`

**Note** Use `WASD` for control as arrow keys are not safe in stack overflow snippets

**Note** you need to focus the snippet for the keyboard events to be seen as stack overflow snippets can not automatically focus.

```js
const keys = (() => {
  const keys = { // only names of keys you are interested in
    KeyW: false,
    KeyS: false,
    Space: false,
  };
  function listener(e) {
    keys[e.code] !== undefined && (keys[e.code] = e.type === "keydown");
    e.preventDefault(); // to stop stack overflow snippet problems
  }
  addEventListener("keyup", listener);
  addEventListener("keydown", listener);
  return keys;
})();

const P2 = (x, y) => ({x, y});  // creates 2D point
const Car = {                   // common properties for a car
    on: false,
    col: "#888",

    /* Function that inspects keyboard state and moves car */
    update() {
        if (this.on) {             // only if active
            let mx = 0, my = 0;
            if (keys.KeyW) {    /* Check forward */
                mx += this.dir.x * 3;
                my += this.dir.y * 3;
            } 
            if (keys.KeyS) {    /* Check reverse */ 
                mx -= this.dir.x;
                my -= this.dir.y;
            } 

            // Keep on canvas 
            if (this.pos.x + mx > W - 40 || this.pos.x + mx <  40) { mx = 0; }
            if (this.pos.y + my > H - 40 || this.pos.y + my <  40) { my = 0; }
            this.pos.x += mx;
            this.pos.y += my;
        }
    
    },
    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.col;
        const sx = this.size.x, sy = this.size.y;
        ctx.setTransform(this.dir.y, this.dir.x, -this.dir.x, this.dir.y, this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
        ctx.fillRect(sx * -0.5, sy * -0.5,  sx, sy);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#9AD";
        ctx.fillRect(sx * -0.4, sy * -0.4,  sx * 0.1, sy * 0.25);
        ctx.fillRect(sx * -0.4, sy * -0.1,  sx * 0.8, sy * 0.2);
        ctx.fillRect(sx *  0.3, sy * -0.4,  sx * 0.1, sy * 0.25);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#EA5";
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.beginPath();
        if (this.on) {
            ctx.moveTo(sx * -0.4 , sy * 1.5);
            ctx.lineTo(sx * -0.25, sy * 0.5);
            ctx.lineTo(sx * -0.1 , sy * 1.5);                
            ctx.moveTo(sx * 0.4 , sy * 1.5);
            ctx.lineTo(sx * 0.25, sy * 0.5);
            ctx.lineTo(sx * 0.1 , sy * 1.5);            
        }
        ctx.moveTo(sx * -0.1 , sy * 0.5);
        ctx.lineTo(sx * -0.4 , sy * 0.5);            
        ctx.moveTo(sx * 0.1 , sy * 0.5);
        ctx.lineTo(sx * 0.4 , sy * 0.5);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // restore default transform incase
                                            // you draw stuff not using setTransform
    }
}
const cars = [{
        dir: P2(0, 1),  // forward direction
        size: P2(30, 50),
        pos: P2(100, 100),
        ...Car
    }, {
        dir: P2(0, -1),  // forward direction
        size: P2(30, 50),
        pos: P2(200, 100),
        ...Car
    }, 
];


requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"), W = canvas.width, H = canvas.height;
var carOnIdx = 0;
cars[carOnIdx].on = true;


function renderLoop(time) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#555";
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, W - 20, H - 20);
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "#DDD";
    ctx.fillRect(70, 10, 2, H - 20);
    ctx.fillRect(130, 10, 2, H - 20);
    ctx.fillRect(175, 10, 2, H - 20);
    ctx.fillRect(225, 10, 2, H - 20);
    
    // If space key press changed cars
    if (keys.Space) {
        cars[carOnIdx].on = false;
        carOnIdx = (carOnIdx + 1) % cars.length;
        cars[carOnIdx].on = true;
        
        // Only want the key down for space to flag it as used
        keys.Space = false;
    }
    for (const car of cars) { car.update(); }
    for (const car of cars) { car.draw(); }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}
```

```css
* {
    font-family: arial;
}
canvas {
    background: #4A6;

}
.info {
    position: absolute;
    left: 340px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: large;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 320px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<div class="info">Using keyboard input</div>
<ul>
<li>To focus keyboard on snippet, click snippet</li>
<li>Uses WASD rather than arrow keys</li>
<li>Space to switch cars</li>
<li>W to drive forward</li>
<li>D to reverse</li>
<li><b>Note</b> cars can not go outside canvas</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and your pointers, however i realized i omitted some  crucial information in my question, my code works fine on the left side of the road but it not on the right side of the road where the down arrow is supposed to the forward value. do you have any advice for that  @Blindman67 ?

Comment: @Nkango You have not provided the code that moves the cars, ie the code that checks `if (this.forward) {` and then changes the cars coordinates.  Each car must have a direction, and thus to move the car forward you use the direction to move the car. See demo snippet labeled with comment `/* Check forward */`